# Can I script actions while screensaver is engaged and a USB device is attached?

Tags: usb, screensaver, disk-volume

I have a Mac mini running Mojave that starts a screensaver at login.

The screensaver is with password prompt, meaning that until a password is entered, it will not show the desktop.  I only have the screen saver enabled; power saver is set to not go to sleep.

I'm checking the machine with a Remote Desktop service (DWService) and browsing the file system. The USB Drive I attached did not mount.

Currently I have to

1. Enter screensaver password
2. detach USB
3. reattach USB

I would like to avoid this behavior, as I use folder action automation to start some process when I plug a USB storage with a magic file present on that drive.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: If I hadn't already read your other question in Super User - https://superuser.com/questions/1516438/folder-actions-and-screensaver-issue - this would be even less clear what you're trying to achieve. Would you like to consolidate your questions into one, with full background information?

Comment: Not sure why you post similar questions both on SU and here (the SU question would be on-topic on AD as well), but as Tetsujin said: Please consolidate and post on one site only.

Comment: Having said that: I can't reproduce this here. After locking the screen and logging in via ssh I still see all the mounted drives (USB and Network) under /Volumes. Can you (besides consolidating) edit your question to show the steps you do and also how the mounts disappear (e.g. with screenshots)?

Comment: Liuk. Seems you are a non native speaker or need to get some editing help. When you keep taking on more information in no order, that tends to get more down votes. I hope I captured your case correctly with my edit.

Comment: Just some more clarification...is this the screensaver that comes built in with macOS or is this some after market software?  Instead of the screen saver can you try putting *just* the display to sleep for now?

Comment: @Allan, it is a standard Screensaver "Message". I'll try the sleep function now and see what happens, thanks!

Comment: @Allan: update. same thing happens with display sleep (after a "pmset displaysleepnow" from terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Finder actions / folder actions are blocked while the screensaver is engaged, so you will need another solution for automation if you need it running while locked.

- https://superuser.com/questions/1516438/folder-actions-and-screensaver-issue

Your stub code seems well designed to start to learn, but perhaps a different automation tech is needed for your end goals?

Comment: Thanks bmike, and yes, I was a posting late in the night after a whole day trying to understand the issue: I guess it was showing!

So, at least I'm thankful someone was able to read my gibberish and confirm the issue! ;-)
What I found today is that not only the Folder Action is disabled, but also the recognition of my attached USB. Because if I mount my USB while the screensaver is on I cannot see it showing on my finder, nor in Disk Utility.

Is it a system-wide security measure or is there any way to bypass it?